# Constructing layer 2 frames using raw sockets

Tags: rust

Is it possible to work with raw sockets in rust?
I want to build my own ethernet tester and send my own constructed layer 2 frames

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You should include a minimal, complete, reproducible example in your question, otherwise it's very difficult to help. You can find a guide on how to make a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If instead you want to ask a more open-ended question, the Rust subreddit or official forums are probably a better place to ask. As your question stands at the moment, it is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are looking for the [pcap](https://docs.rs/pcap/latest/pcap/) crate, which is a Rusty set of bindings to libpcap. This library offers facilities for capturing packets from and injecting packets to network devices, and can operate at different layers (Ethernet being one of them, for Ethernet devices).

It does not provide mechanisms to build or parse frames, but those are simple enough to build oneself.